# WMIC commands in powershell

Tags: powershell

How can I do the same think as the following WMIC commands in powershell?

```
wmic UserAccount where Name='LocalUser' set PasswordExpires=False

wmic useraccount where name='LocalUser' set passwordchangeable=false
```

Comment: What version of PowerShell?

Answer (score 4):

With the WMI cmdlets available since version 2.0 of PowerShell, that would be something like:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter 'Name = "LocalUser"' |Set-WmiInstance -Arguments @{PasswordExpires=$false}
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter 'Name = "LocalUser"' |Set-WmiInstance -Arguments @{PasswordChangeable=$false}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have PowerShell 5.1, you can use:

```
Set-LocalUser -Name 'LocalUser' -PasswordNeverExpires:$false -UserMayChangePassword:$false
```